# Image not saving to uploads folder node multer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer

After specifying the path for the uploaded image to `./uploads` my images are still going towards tmp folder.

[image: folder tree]

[image]

My multer configuration

```
const multer = require("multer");
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    desitnation: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, './uploads/');
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
})
const upload = multer({storage: storage});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the spelling `desitnation` is wrongly spelled. It should be `destination`.